# Get the foreign key in a httpRequest in nestJs

Tags: database, foreign-keys, nestjs

I'm trying to make many request in nestJs and specially some with the role of my users and i wanted to be able to list all users who match user.role = "Role's name" but i can't get the foreign key user from my table role.

My controller look like this and both of my entities reference each other as a role can have one or many user and a user one and only one role.

```
import { Controller, Get, Param, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Body } from '@nestjs/common/decorators';
import { AuthDto } from 'src/authentification/auth.dto';
import { Role } from './role.entity';
import { User } from './user.entity';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Controller('user')
export class UserController {
    constructor(private readonly UserService: UserService){}

    @Get()
    async getAllUser(): Promise<User[]>{
        return this.UserService.getListUser();
    }

    @Get('/Role')
    async getListRole(): Promise<Role[]> {
        return this.UserService.getListRole();
    }

    @Get('/Role/:role')
    async getUserByRole(@Param('role') role : number): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.UserService.getUserByRole(+role);
    }

    @Get('/Pseudo/:pseudo')
    async getUserByPseudo(@Param('pseudo') pseudo : string): Promise<User> {
        return this.UserService.getUserByPseudo(pseudo);
    }

    @Get('/id/:id')
    async getUserById(@Param('id') id : number): Promise<User> {
        return this.UserService.getUserById(+id);
    }

    @Post('/New')
    async createUser(@Body() user: AuthDto){
        return this.UserService.createUser(user);
    }
}
```

and here is the service

```
import { Get, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AuthDto } from 'src/authentification/auth.dto';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Role } from './role.entity';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(User) private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
        @InjectRepository(Role) private rolesRepository: Repository<Role>
    ){}

    getUserById(id): Promise<User> {
        return this.usersRepository.findOneOrFail(id);
    }

    getUserByPseudo(pseudo: string): Promise<User> {
        return this.usersRepository.findOne({pseudo});
    }

    getListRole(): Promise<Role[]> {
        return this.rolesRepository.find();
    }

    getListUser(): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.usersRepository.find();
    }

    getUserByRole(role): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.usersRepository.find({where: {role: role}});
    }

    createUser(data: AuthDto){
        const user = {
            pseudo: data.username,
            password: data.password,
            pointEffort: 10,
            scienceTab: [],
            inventaire: [],
            technologieTab: [],
            role: {
                id: 1,
                nom: "joueur",
                users: []
            },
        };
        const result = this.usersRepository.save(user);
        return result;
    }
}
```

user.entity.ts

```
import { Place } from "src/place/place.entity";
import { Science } from "src/science/science.entity";
import { TechnologieUser } from "src/technologie/technologieUser.entity";
import { Column, Entity, ManyToMany, ManyToOne, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { Role } from "./role.entity";

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: Number;

    @Column()
    pseudo: String;

    @Column()
    password: String;

    @Column()
    pointEffort: Number;

    @ManyToOne(type => Role, role => role.users)
    role: Role;

    @ManyToMany(type => Science, science => science.users)
    scienceTab: Science[];

    @OneToMany(type => TechnologieUser, technologieUser => technologieUser.user)
    technologieTab: TechnologieUser[];

    @OneToMany(type => Place, place => place.user)
    inventaire: Place[];
}
```

role.entity.ts

```
import { Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./user.entity";

@Entity()
export class Role {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: Number;

    @Column()
    nom: String;

    @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.role)
    users: User[];
}
```

But when i use getListRole() i only get this [image: no foreign key]

And so i don't have the list of my users returned in the property role.users which is missing.
So the question is : how can i have role.users added in the data of getListRole()?
Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Get role id from params, then do, `this.usersRepository.find({ relations: {Role: true}, where: { role: { id: roleId } } })`

Comment: I've tried your solution but it gets me an error "ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot find alias for relation at role".
here is the controller : 
@Get('/Role')
    async getListRole(@Param('roleId') roleId : number): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.UserService.getListRole(+roleId);
    }

and here the service :
    getListRole(roleId): Promise<User[]> {
        return this.usersRepository.find({ where: { role: { id: roleId } } })
    }

Comment: @djodjoxyz could you please add your typeorm models to your post

Comment: also I edited my answer please check it

Comment: i've updated it and testing your new answer but i can't assign a boolean to a string[] type

Comment: @djodjoxyz try changing the relations in find conditions to `relations: ['role']`. The syntax shared in the answer is only working for typeorm@3.x.

Comment: @Dmitrii Tkachenko yep it works with this syntax thanks a lot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).